# Predict if probability is higher than certain value

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am using a MLP  model for classification.

When I predict for new data, I want to keep only those predictions whose probability of prediction is larger than 0.5, and change all other predictions into class 0.

How can I do it in keras ?

I'm using using last layer as follows
`model.add(layers.Dense(7 , activation='softmax'))`

Is it meaningful to get predictions with probability larger than 0.5 using the softmax?

```
newdata = (nsamples, nfeatures)
predictions = model.predict (newdata)
print (predictions.shape)
(500, 7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
preds=model.predict etc
index=np.argmax(preds)
probability= preds(index)
if probability >=.75:
    print (' class is ', index,' with high confidence')
elif probability >=.5:
    print (' class is ', index,' with medium confidence')
else:
    print (' class is ', index,' with low confidence')
```

Answer (score 1):

Softmax function outputs **probabilities**. So in your case you will have 7 classes and their probability sum will be equal to 1.

Now consider a case `[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]` which is the output of the softmax. Appyling a threshold in that case would not make sense as you can see.

Threshold 0.5 has nothing to do with n-classed predictions. It is something special for binary classification.

For to get classes, you should use argmax.

Edit: If you want to drop your predictions if they are under a certain threshold, you can use, but that's **not a correct way to deal** with  multi-class predictions:

```
labels = []
threshold = 0.5

for probs_thresholded in out:
   labels.append([])
   
   for i in range(len(probs_thresholded)):
      if probs_thresholded[i] >= threshold:
         labels[-1].append(1)
      else:
         labels[-1].append(0)
```

Comment: it means, since the max proba is 0.3, prediction would be class `7` right ?

Comment: Exactly. With argmax you return the index of the maximum value.

Comment: Then, can we say that prediction probability of label `7` is 0.3. Since its less than `0.5`, we convert it into `0` ?

Comment: Converting it to 0 does not make any sense. If you convert it to 0 you lose your prediction. As I said with n-class predictions with softmax, no threshold is involved to get classes & predictions.

Comment: Since it might lead false information I avoid showing it, you can simply mask your prediction array with list comprehension.

Comment: how do you think about, `model.predict_proba` using Random Forests classifier? these probability values are meaningful right ?

Comment: Same thing but I added the code if you want to drop some prediction probabilities.

Comment: what would be correct way to deal with multi-class predictions?

Comment: You should use argmax to get to index of highest probability, if you're model is trained good enough, there will be dominant class most of the times.

Comment: i know it, but i need probability of that prediction, i.e., class 7

Comment: Softmax returns probabilities,  `predictions = model.predict (newdata)`, when you print predictions, you will get probabilities. Index 6 will be the probability of class 7.

Comment: why its special for binary classification but not meaningful for multi-classes classification ?